# Sheaf cohomology commutes with colimits of sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology, limits-and-colimits

Let $X$ be a Noetherian scheme over a Noetherian ring $R$ and $(F_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in I}$ a direct system of $O_X$-module sheaves on $X$. I'm looking for source literature where I can find a proof of the fact that colimits of sheaves commute with sheaf cohomology, ie that for all $i\ge0$ the canonical morphism of $R$-modules

$$\varinjlim_i H^{i}(X, F_{\alpha}) \to H^i(X, \varinjlim_{\alpha} F_{\alpha}) $$

induced by $F_{\alpha} \to \varinjlim_{\alpha} F_{\alpha}$, applying the naturality of cohomology functor and the universal property of colimits. That's of course a well known fact used by people involved in research on algebraic geometry literally by reflex but I nowhere found a well explained proof of this isomorphism.

Comment: See the last paragraph of section II.4.12 in Godement, Topologie algébrique et théorie des faisceaux.

Comment: Or Tag [01FF](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01FF) (which implies the result for quasi-compact quasi-separated schemes).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the canonical reference (true for any coherent topos, so for every qcqs scheme, as Remy mentions) is SGA 4 II, Expose VI, Corollaire 5.2.

> Let $E'$ be a coherent topos. For every integer $q$, the functor $H^q(E', -)$ commutes with filtered inductive limits of abelian sheaves.

Answer (score 2):

> Hartshorne Chapter 3 Proposition 2.9

can be apply to this case